# Как поменять кодировку файла на ansi-1251?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Когда открываю файл который в кодировке 1251, выводятся знаки вопроса на месте русских символов.

Comment: Ось Винда? Какой язык установлен для неюникодных программ?

Comment: Где открываете? как открываете? куда и как выводите? "... у меня в подполе происходит стук ..."

Comment: Винда. Sublime text так же открывает, но там есть опция File-> reopen with encoding. А как проверить какой язык установлен для неюникодовых программ?

Comment: Контрольная панель > Регион (последняя вкладка). Зависит от версии винды.

Comment: Там стоит русский.

Comment: Кликните на `UTF-8` в статус-баре, выберите "Reopen with encoding" и выберите нужную кодировку.

Comment: Ок, спасибо это помогло!

Comment: А минус за что поставили?